# difference between push and normal array assignment in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, api

I'm using  [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) api to draw charts. Look at this chart type [HERE](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/interacting.html).
In that example they've used values like,

```
var sin = [], cos = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 14; i += 0.5) {
        sin.push([i, Math.sin(i)]);
        cos.push([i, Math.cos(i)]);
  }
```

Now the chart was drawn "curved" lines, when i replaced the

```
sin.push([i, Math.sin(i)]);
cos.push([i, Math.cos(i)]);
```

with,

```
sin[i]=[i, Math.sin(i)];
cos[i]=[i, Math.cos(i)];
```

Then the chart gets drawn using straight lines. I've two questions now.

1) What is the difference between the two types of array assignments?
2) Is this because of difference in array assignments or the API behaviour?

any help greatly appreciated! Thanks.

**Edit:** Set i to increment by 1 and set different values using push method or default assignment, you'll get the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The i is not Integer. You can use only int in array index.

1) What is the difference between the two types of array assignments?
A) None, except the push places next int for index.

2) Is this because of difference in array assignments or the API behaviour?
A) Yes with your way the array is invalid, because the 1.5 value for a key is parsed as a string and api can not read the array as it expect.

Try using apis way or using different values for for statement.

Comment: Now i incremented array assignments incremented by 1, now it works fine.. a silly mistake made me hours to solve

Answer (score 3):

I think there's a problem with `i` increment. It is clear that on every iteration `i` is increased by 0.5, not 1. Look:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 14; i += 0.5)
```

So `sin[i]=...` won't work properly. But `sin.push(...)` will work.

Comment: Thanks, but I've made a mistake. I've set i to increment by 1 and by each value i've given different values. Now i tried to use these two assignment types but still getting getting the same result

Answer (score 2):

Array indexes can't be fractions and are always strings, so the *number* 1.5 is being converted to a string '1.5' and the sequence will be '0', '0.5', '1', '1.5' and so on. But using *push*, all indexes will be integer strings, so will be 0, 1, 2, etc.

No doubt an integer based loop is being used to read the values from the array, so it is skipping the .5 ones (i.e. every second element) and giving jagged edges.

Comment: I think you're pointed the exact thing, i checked using values of sin array using alert, after every element i got an "undefined" alert, so is this making to draw curved lines?

Comment: Lachezar Todorov also pointed the same thing, so we've go with api's way. Thanks for all.

Answer (score 1):

Generally this would work, but in this case you're incrementing `i` by `0.5` which results in `i` being a `float`-value.

Look at the output of both variants:

```
// push
// cos
[[0, 1], 
 [0.5, 0.8775825618903728], 
 [1, 0.5403023058681398], 
 [1.5, 0.0707372016677029], 
 [2, -0.4161468365471424], 
 [2.5, -0.8011436155469337], ...]

// sin
[[0, 0], 
 [0.5, 0.479425538604203], 
 [1, 0.8414709848078965], 
 [1.5, 0.9974949866040544], 
 [2, 0.9092974268256817], 
 [2.5, 0.5984721441039564], ...]

// array-index
// cos
[[0, 1], 
 [1, 0.5403023058681398], 
 [2, -0.4161468365471424], 
 [3, -0.9899924966004454], 
 [4, -0.6536436208636119], ...]

// sin
[[0, 0], 
 [1, 0.8414709848078965], 
 [2, 0.9092974268256817], 
 [3, 0.1411200080598672], 
 [4, -0.7568024953079282], ...]
```